# How to parse bigger amount of words?

Tags: c

I have a program, which receives filename as an input, saves file contents into 2d char array and then outputs words. It works absolutely fine for about 400 words, but then, when I add more words, it crashes. Debugging showed that i am trying to access unused address, and I don't understand how is that possible considering that previous tests with lesser amount of words were successful.

The question is: what am i missing here?

**FILE:** *functions.c*

```
#include "Lab10.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
char** parser(char* filename) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    char** str = (char**)calloc(N, sizeof(char*) * N);
    if (!str)
    {
        printf("\n Allocation error");
        return NULL;
    }

    char ch;
    int space = 0, words = 0;
    for (int i = 0; !feof(fp); i++)                        // Memory allocation
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (!is_ch(ch))
        {
            if (i != space)
            {
                if (!(str[words] = (char*)calloc(i - space, sizeof(char) * (i - space))))
                {
                    printf("\n Allocation error");
                    return NULL;
                }
                words++;
            }

            while (!is_ch(ch) && !feof(fp))
            {
                ch = fgetc(fp);
                i++;
            }
            if(!feof(fp))
                fseek(fp, -(int)sizeof(char), 1);
            i--;
            space = i;
        }
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; i < words; i++)                       // Copying words into 2d array
    {
        while (!is_ch(fgetc(fp)));
        if (!feof(fp))
            fseek(fp, -(int)sizeof(char), 1);

        int j = 0;
        do {
            if (((fscanf(fp, "%c", &str[i][j])) != 1))
                break;
            j++;
        } while (is_ch(str[i][j-1]) && !feof(fp));
    }
    return str;
}

int is_ch(char ch)
{
    return ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'));
}
```

**FILE:** *main.c*

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "Lab10.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * N);
    if (!scanf("%s", filename) || filename == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Incorrect filename input");
        return -1;
    }

    char** str = parser(filename);

    printf("\n Contents of .txt file:");
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("\n\t%d) ", i+1);
        for (int j = 0; is_ch(str[i][j]); j++) {
            printf("%c", str[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really not the way to write C++ code. Apart from the fact that you named your files with a `.cpp` extensions, and are presumably compiling this with a C++ compiler, the code itself looks to be entirely C.

Comment: Since this is tagged C++, the appropriate solution is to use `std::vector<std::string>` to manage that array of strings.

Comment: @cigien, there was a typo in a question itself, i fixed it, thank you

Comment: That first `if` statement in `main` should have its conditions the other way around: `if (filename == 0  || !scanf("%s", filename))`. That way, if the allocation fails, the code won't call `scanf`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, i deleted tag C++, - another typo. The idea is to do that using C

Comment: `if (!scanf("%s", filename) || filename == 0)` wrong, you cannot do something with `filename` and *then* check if it's good to do that.

Comment: You use N as the number of characters in `filename` and also as the number of words in the file. This is probably not a good way to use arbitrary constants. You are counting the number of words in the first pass over the file, why not use that to allocate the words array after you have finished counting? I **strongly** suggest to write a function `readWord`. Your life will be so much easier with it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., oh my... thank you very much, that is really a thing!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., you must've been mistaken. I use N only to read filename

Comment: `char** str = (char**)calloc(N, sizeof(char*) * N);`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., can you, please, explain how readWord should work? I consider posting this explanation as an answer a great idea, if you would, of course

Comment: For example it could work like `fgets` but stop at any a non-letter rather than just at the newline character. There are many possible interfaces, it doesn't really matter which one you choose.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted as a reply to one of the comments below the question itself. I tried writing readWord function, which recieves filepointer, reads one word and then returns pointer to the resulting array - that's eases the procedure, making it less complex. It works almost like fgets(), but it reads till non-character, instead of a newline

*readWord function itself*:

```
char* readWord(FILE* fp) {
    char ch = 0;

    while (!is_ch(ch))
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF || !ch)
            return NULL;
    }
    
    int size = 1;
    while (is_ch(ch))
    {
        if ((ch = fgetc(fp)) == EOF || !ch)
            break;
        size++;
    }
    fseek(fp, -(size * (int)sizeof(char)), 1);

    if (ch != EOF || !ch)
        size--;

    char* word = (char*)calloc(size, sizeof(char) * size + 1);
    if (!word)
    {
        printf("\n Allocation error.");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        word[i] = fgetc(fp);
    word[size] = '\0';

    return word;
}
```

*That's how i use it in main()*:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
char* word;

while ((word = readWord(fp)) != NULL)
{
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%c", word[i]);
    printf(" ");
}
```

Is there is anything i need to improve here? It works fine, but is it possible to somehow make it better?

Comment: File I/O (although probably buffered already) and memory allocation are two generally slow operations; if you are finding this the bottleneck, consider reading/allocating a larger amount into memory and then working on this buffer.